# TLS 1.2 implementation in C++ Windows Application using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl, visual-studio-2019, tls1.2

I have a windows application that works as a client and installed on multiple device and they can communicate with each other, Now I want to encrypt the communication. I tried to found out some methods like Microsoft's SSPI library and SChannel but didn't find an easy implementation, So I am trying with the OpenSSL.

I am trying to create a client and server using winsocket and enabling TLS communication using OpenSSL in Visual Studio 2019. THe problem is it gets connect to the server, the server prints the message connected to client and also client code show connected, but on SSL_Connect method it fails and shows no error in the client code! I also created a normal TCP socket server and try to connect it to this as well than also it fails after connecting.

What is going wrong! Here is my code:

Client:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define FAIL    -1

//Added the LoadCertificates how in the server-side makes.    
void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

int OpenConnection(const char* hostname, int port)
{
    int sd;
    struct hostent* host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        printf("winsock error");
        return 0;
    }

    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
    {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        closesocket(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD* method = TLS_client_method(); /* Create new client-method instance */
    SSL_CTX* ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
   // method = SSLv3_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509* cert;
    char* line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if (cert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("No certificates.\n");
}

int main()
{
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    int server;
    SSL* ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char hostname[] = "127.0.0.1";
    char portnum[] = "54000";
    char CertFile[] = "C:/Users/cert/Documents/testing/ec_crt.pem";
    char KeyFile[] = "C:/Users/cert/Documents/testing/private-key.pem";

    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile);
    
    printf("clinet certificate loaded");
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL)   /* perform the connection */ {
        printf("Connection failed");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    else
    {
        const char* msg = "Hello???";

        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certs */
        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encrypt & send message */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */
    }
    closesocket(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

SERVER:

//SSL-Server.c

```
#include <errno.h>

#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>


#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")


#define FAIL    -1

int OpenListener(int port)
{
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        printf("winsock error");
        return 0;
    }

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
        perror("can't bind port");
        abort();
    }
    if (listen(sd, 10) != 0)
    {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    listen(sd, SOMAXCONN);
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD* method = TLS_client_method(); /* Create new client-method instance */
    SSL_CTX* ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    //New lines 
    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

    if (SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    //End new lines

    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }

    //New lines - Force the client-side have a certificate
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
    //End new lines
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509* cert;
    char* line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* Get certificates (if available) */
    if (cert != NULL)
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        X509_free(cert);
    }
    else
        printf("No certificates.\n");
}

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{
    char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes;
    const char* HTMLecho = "<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

    if (SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL)     /* do SSL-protocol accept */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certificates */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
        if (bytes > 0)
        {
            buf[bytes] = 0;
            printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
           // sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   /* construct reply */
            SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* send reply */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    closesocket(sd);          /* close connection */
}

int main()
{
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    int server;
    char portnum[] = "54000";

    char CertFile[] = "C:/Users/cert/Documents/testing/ec_crt.pem";
    char KeyFile[] = "C:/Users/cert/Documents/testing/private-key.pem";

    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile); /* load certs */
    printf("Certificate loaded");
    server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));    /* create server socket */
    while (1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL* ssl;

        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  /* accept connection as usual */
        //printf("Connection: %s:%d\n", inet_ntop(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
        printf("Connected");
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* get new SSL state with context */
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);      /* set connection socket to SSL state */
        Servlet(ssl);         /* service connection */
    }
    closesocket(server);          /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* release context */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use:

```
const SSL_METHOD* method = TLS_server_method();
```

in `InitServerCtx()`?

Comment: its already there!